# how to change confige react-mui-draft-wysiwyg?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, node-modules, html-editor

I use HTML editor material ui :

```
import MUIEditor, { MUIEditorState } from "react-mui-draft-wysiwyg";

 <MUIEditor
    editorState={formElement.editorState}
    onChange={formElement.onChange}
  />
```

I want to remove the font color button in the toolbar. When I go to the MUIEditor file at node-modules and I want to make some changes to that file but it does not seem to change even when I get a console I can not see the result. What should I do?

```
 .node_modules
        .react-mui-draft-wysiwyg
           .dist
             .index.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rarely advisable to edit the contents of `/node_modules` -- instead `react-mui-draft-wysiwyg` provides direct a way to customize the toolbar configuration through the `config` prop, in your own React code.

In your case, to hide the font color button, you simply need to pass in the menu options that you would like to display. (ie. remove/comment out the `toolbarControlTypes.fontColor` option). For example:

```
    import MUIEditor, {
      MUIEditorState,
      toolbarControlTypes // Added toolbarControlTypes
    } from "react-mui-draft-wysiwyg";

...

    <MUIEditor
      editorState={editorState}
      onChange={onChange}
      config={{
        toolbar: {
          controls: [
            toolbarControlTypes.undo,
            toolbarControlTypes.redo,
            toolbarControlTypes.divider,
            toolbarControlTypes.bold,
            toolbarControlTypes.italic,
            toolbarControlTypes.underline,
            toolbarControlTypes.strikethrough,
            // Include all of the default toolbar options except for fontColor
            // toolbarControlTypes.fontColor,
            toolbarControlTypes.fontBackgroundColor,
            toolbarControlTypes.divider,
            toolbarControlTypes.linkAdd,
            toolbarControlTypes.linkRemove,
            toolbarControlTypes.image,
            toolbarControlTypes.divider,
            toolbarControlTypes.blockType,
            toolbarControlTypes.fontSize,
            toolbarControlTypes.fontFamily,
            toolbarControlTypes.textAlign,
            toolbarControlTypes.divider,
            toolbarControlTypes.unorderedList,
            toolbarControlTypes.orderedList
          ]
        }
      }}
    />
```

Documentation: [Default Configuration Options](https://kelsier90.github.io/react-mui-draft-wysiwyg/configuration/default-configuration)

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui4-draft-wysiwyg-bre8e?file=/demo.js